# onSeekPoint weirdness

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, netstream

I have a NetStream which is put into data generation mode properly... everything works fine and I get onSeekPoint() events when I do something like the following:

**EXAMPLE 1**

```
public function setupStream() {
     netStream.client = {};
     netStream.client.onSeekPoint = this.onSeekPoint;
     netStream.client.onMetaData = this.onMetaData;
}

public function onSeekPoint(... args) {...}
public function onMetaData(... args) {...}
```

However, instead of keeping it all in that parent class, I need to create a new class for the client which also has that onSeekPoint. It doesn't work. Strangely, the onMetaData callback does... it's something like this:

**EXAMPLE 2**

```
package {
   public class CustomClient {
       public function CustomClient() {
       }
       public function onSeekPoint(... args) {...}
       public function onMetaData(... args) {...}
   }
}

public function setupStream() {
   var myClient:CustomClient = new CustomClient();
   netStream.client = CustomClient;
}
```

I thought that maybe there's some small issue I missed- but what's really freaking me out, is that this fully works properly...

**EXAMPLE 3**

```
package {
   public class CustomClient {
       public function CustomClient() {
       }
       public function onSeekPoint(... args) {...}
       public function onMetaData(... args) {...}
   }
}

public function setupStream() {
   var myClient:CustomClient = new CustomClient();
   netStream.client = {};
   netStream.client.onSeekPoint = myClient.onSeekPoint;
   netStream.client.onMetaData = myClient.onMetaData
}
```

I guess "if it ain't broke don't fix it" might apply here, but I'm a little worried letting some code I don't understand go, and afraid it might come back to bite me when I least expect it ;)

My questions are:

1. Why doesn't the second example work for seekPoints?
2. Ok then- why *does* the second example work for metaData?
3. Why does the third example fix everything?

**EDIT**: In case it's unclear, the different classes are correctly in separate files, etc. They're just combined in the examples here to make it easier to digest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your second example you have this:

```
var myClient:CustomClient = new CustomClient();
netStream.client = CustomClient;
```

But shouldn't it be something like this:

```
var myClient:CustomClient = new CustomClient();
netStream.client = myClient;
```